# How to filter characters not in filter characters in [^\u0000-\uFFFF] using c#

Tags: .net

These codepoints cause a problem when my application tries to process an email with them.

Comment: Why I downvoted this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149138/133242

Answer (score 1):

C# strings are UTF-16 encoded, so *every* `char` element of the string is a code unit that necessarily falls into the range `[\u0000-\uFFFF]`. If you simply want to remove every Unicode code point from the string which requires 2 code units in UTF-16 encoding, then you'll need to remove every instance of a character `[\uD800-\uDBFF]` which is immediately followed by a character in the range `[\uDC00-\uDFFF]`. Alternately, I believe you could simply remove every character in the range `[\uD800-\uDFFF]` and accomplish the same task.

The result may not be useful as I imagine the surrogate pairs were originally introduced for a specific reason, causing the meaning of the string to change if you filter them out. The best solution is updating your application to handle them properly.